# Hints about two measure related tasks (almost everywhere problems).

Tags: measure-theory, functions, convergence-divergence

I got these two tasks as exercises on my measure theory lectures, and somehow I have no idea where to start. I tried a few approaches (and made some research for similar problems, but it didn't help me anyway). I'll greatly appreciate any hint, or solution to these :)

1) Let $f_n$ be sequence of measurable functions, such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in terms of given measure, and $|f_n|<M$. Prove that $|f|\le M$ almost everywhere.

2) Let $f_n$ be sequence of measurable functions, such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in terms of given measure, and sequence $f_n$ is nondecreasing. Prove that $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere.

With the first one, I tried to rewrite the $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ property using triangle inequality, but this lead me to nowhere. Also I tried to prove it by contradiction, but it seems even harder then original task.

With the second one I don't even have idea where to start.

Comment: Re 1): As it is stated now, the assertion is not correct. In general, $|f| \color{red}{\leq} M$ a.e. is the best we can expect.

Comment: Sorry for inconvinience, I made mistake :) Now it will be correct I suppose

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you know that $f_n \to f$ in measure implies $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost everywhere for a suitable subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ of $(f_n)_n$?

Comment: Is my reasoning correct that if I use that implication, then for this subsequence if $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n = f$ almost everywhere, then straightforward from $|f_n|<M$ we have that $|f| \le M$ almost everywhere?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.... that's why I was asking whether you know this statement. However, there are also other ways to prove it (which are not even more difficult and, essentially, use the triangle inequality).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I don't know how I have not connected those two together. Also... how the non-decreasing property of $f_n$ gives us convergence almost everywhere? Because still, I do not know how to apply it to my subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Question 1: As mentioned in a comment, we know that $f_n \to f$ in measure implies the existence of a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost everywhere. This easily proves the assertion.

However, there is also a more elementary proof based on the triangle inequality. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since

$$\{x; |f(x)| \geq M+\epsilon\} \subseteq \{x; |f(x)-f_n(x)| \geq \epsilon\} \cup \{x; |f_n(x)| \geq M\}$$

we have

$$\mu(|f| \geq M+\epsilon) \leq \mu(|f-f_n| \geq \epsilon) + \mu(|f_n| \geq M).$$

By assumption, the second term on the right-hand side equals $0$ and the first one converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence, $\mu(|f| \geq M+\epsilon)=0$. As $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, this proves $\mu(|f|>M)=0$.

---

Regarding Question 2: I take it that you mean by "non-decreasing sequence" that for any $x$ we have $f_1(x) \leq f_2(x) \leq f_3(x) \leq \ldots$. Because of this monotonicity, the function

$$g(x) := \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n(x)$$

is well-defined and $f_n \to g$ pointwise. Since pointwise convergence implies convergence in measure and limits in measure are unique, this gives $\mu(f \neq g)=0$; in particular, $f_n \to f=g$ almost everywhere.